# What could cause string concatenation to fail?

Tags: php, curl

The following code lives on one of my servers:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = "http://www.example.com/controller/action?param1=" . $value1 . "&param2=" . $value2;
    $url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Most of the time, this works just fine. However, today in example.com's access logs, I noticed an entry where the second parameter was completely missing.  Not just the value, the entire parameter.  So the log line was

> GET /controller/action?param1=36838242 HTTP/1.1

I can't think of any condition what would cause `param2` to be completely missing from the querystring. However, obviously it happened.  And there is only one block of code that makes this curl call, so this is definitely the code responsible for the access log entry.

So my question is, under what condition could part of a concatenation fail, but have the rest of the code continue running? Since the code works 99% of the time, I'd love to write it off as a fluke, but this is really bugging me.

Comment: Maybe `$value1` got a 0 byte stuck in it somehow?

Comment: String concatenation can not “fail”. What might happen though is that your `$value` contains something that ends the URL there (or at least the part the server gets to see). And finally, that request might not even have come from your code at all (if the server is exposed to other clients on a larger network, like say the internet).

Comment: @CBroe The IP address on the log entry matched my other server.  Plus, I'm the only one who'd be making those requests anyway.

Comment: Instead of handling values with `str_replace` you should do it the _proper_ way, by using `urlencode`.

Comment: Yes, a `#` in `$value1` would do it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$value1` is an internally-generated value (not user input) that I can confirm did not have a `#` in it.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the string concatenation cannot fail.

I'm going to guess that `$value1` contains a some non-printable character that is not being properly encoded. Your `str_replace` is only handling spaces. You would be much safer doing something like this:

```
$params = array( 'param1' => $value1,
                 'param2' => $value2 );

$url = 'http://www.example.com/controller/action?' . http_build_query($params);
```

And dropping the current call to `str_replace`.

Comment: hmmm... While I hate to say it (and I'd be suspect of anyone else saying it), I can pretty much guarantee that `$value1` is a non-NUL string, as it is an ID being pulled from my database (and is written to other log files where I can see its value).

Comment: Fair enough.  In either case the way you are building your URLs is unsafe.  I will leave this answer here as I still believe it has valuable information.  (Unless I am downvoted into oblivion in which case I will remove it)

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree that the querystring building is poor. I'd love to blame it on this being inherited code (which it is), but since I've looked at it a couple times without fixing it, the blame is now on me.  And I also agree that this could be valuable information.  And as unlikely as it is in this case, there's always the saying that, when all impossible scenarios are removed, all that is left, however unlikely, must be the answer :)

Comment: So your `$value1` is coming from an `INT` column in a database that you are not massaging in PHP in any way?  Would it be possible to post some of the actual code that is failing?  Maybe the issue is more subtle.

Comment: `$value1` is extracted from the db on, let's call it `page1.php`, and posted (via a hidden field on a form) to `page2.php`, which is the page with the code included above.  My server logs make me think that the value passed was `36838242`. No manipulation of this value happens between when this value is received by `page2.php` and when `$url` is generated (assuming that Zend didn't bork things in this one case). If I don't see any better answers after a bit, I'll accept this, as there are a couple variables (the form post, Zend's request handling) that I can't guarantee had no impact.

Comment: Don't accept it if it doesn't resolve your issue, but do make sure to come back and post your own answer if you end up figuring out what the issue is.